# Change backend ActiveRecord database for delayed_job in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, delayed-job

I'm working on upgrading a rails app from 2.3.11 to 3.0 (then eventually 3.1), and am changing my delayed_job gem from 2.0.4 to 2.1.4.

There's already a delayed_jobs table in my postgres database, but it is in a different db from the default one for my rails app. For example, in development mode I use the 'development' db, but some of my relations, including delayed_jobs is on the 'development_stats' db. Other models that use this db can access it fine.

In my `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb`, for delayed_job 2.0.4:

```
Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false

class Delayed::Job
  establish_connection Rails.configuration.database_configuration["#{Rails.env}_stats"]
end
```

Now, I'm getting these errors when I try to use delayed_job:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  relation "delayed_jobs" does not exist 
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "delayed_jobs"
```

or

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:56:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_InsertStatement'
```

It seems from other things I've read, that the Delayed::Job model gets loaded now when the gem gets loaded, so it's too late to change the db in an initializer. Has anyone else ran into this issue and been able to find a way to tell delayed_job to use a different db?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me...

Answer (score 1):

this might help, when changing the "name" of the delayed_job table I found that I needed to force rails to reset the associated db schema for the model, as follows:

Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.set_table_name '' 
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.reset_column_information

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following works in my application's boot.rb file (under Padrino) in delayed_job 4.0.2:

`Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.establish_connection xxxxx`